# If $A + B = \frac{\pi}{3} (A,B>0),$ Then the minimum value of sec A + sec B is?

Tags: calculus, optimization

If $A + B = \frac{\pi}{3} (A,B>0),$ Then the minimum value of sec A + sec B is?

I know the condition for minima but here there are two simultaneous variables , how and with respect to what do I differentiate?

Any help is wecolme.

Comment: Hint: $B=\pi/3-A$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Minimize the function

$$f(x) = \sec x + \sec\Big(\frac{\pi}{3} - x\Big)$$

on an appropriate interval for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sec x$. Then $\displaystyle f'(x)=\sec x\cdot \tan x =\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2(x)}$

Now $$f'(x)=\frac{\cos^3 x+2\sin^2 x\cos x}{\cos^4 x}>0\forall x\in \bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{3}\bigg)$$

Function is convex function.

So $$\frac{\sec A+\sec B}{2}\geq \sec \bigg(\frac{A+B}{2}\bigg)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\sec A+\sec B \geq \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Equality hold when $A=B$